# Setting up a VPN tunnel between a Linux box and a Cisco FW

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, cisco, ipsec

I have a linux box (ubuntu) and I have a service provider that will only allow an IPSEC tunnel connection between his network and my linux box.

I have these details from the service provider:

Service Provider: Peer IP – Lan on service provider's side - 10.10.10.10/24

Linux box details: Peer IP - Lan -

Connection details: Phase1: Sha Aes 128 DH - group x Preshared – Lifetime – 24h

Phase2: Sha Aes 128 Lifetime – 1h

I am not sure which app I need to install on the linux box that will support this type of connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: read: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN

Comment: @Tom: Did you read it? IPSec is "Not covered on this page, so far"

Answer (score 2):

There are two implementations of IPSec networking code for Linux.  The first was FreeS/WAN's KLIPS driver for 2.4 kernels.  The second was 2.6's own native IPSec driver.  During early 2.6 versions the native IPSec had fairly serious problems which led to the KLIPS IPSec driver being ported to 2.6.

The kernel-level support is only a piece of the puzzle, IPSec requires a user-space daemon for key exchange.  There are a number of these for Linux.  [OpenS/WAN](http://www.openswan.org/) descends directly from FreeS/WAN and can use either 2.6 native IPSec or the KLIPS modules (KLIPS being preferred).  [strongSwan](http://www.strongswan.org/) is a fork from FreeS/WAN to use native IPSec only.  There are also ports of the BSD IKE daemons for the 2.6 native IPSec driver: [racoon/ipsec-tools](http://ipsec-tools.sourceforge.net/) from Free/NetBSD and isakmpd from OpenBSD.